# Tkinter: how can I have a text area with a scrollbar that fill the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, text, resize, frame

I was wondering if it's possible to have a tk.Text widget next to a tk.Scrollbar and they both fill up the frame and eventually resize if the frame is resized

Here's a couple of pictures to get it clear:

This is how it looks when I start the program:

[image]

This is how it looks as soon as I resize the frame:

[image]

Is there a way to make them both resize?

Comment: try `text.pack(fill='both', expand=1)`

Comment: How do you layout them? `pack()` or `grid()`?

Comment: I use pack(), with grid the scrollbar is very small